# Replace to_utf8string to ensure proper string encoding on Windows 7 in a C++ DLL

Tags: c++, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, windows-7

I have a legacy C++ code that was written as a dll that can be called on Windows 10. A new requirement is to allow this dll to function properly on earlier Windows (7 Embedded, optionally XP as well). In short, the code is supposed to display `body` of a REST response.

The problem is, when called on Windows 7 without any modifications, there are additional (sometimes invisible) characters, especially at the beginning of the displayed output.

The code below is an abbreviated version and I believe `to_utf8string` is the root of the problem. What other function should I use in order for this dll to work on Windows 7 properly?

```
const char* foo(const char* param)
{
    web::http::http_response resp = other_foo(param).get();
    std::string utf8Response;

    web::json::value json = resp.extract_json().get();
    utf8Response = utility::conversions::to_utf8string(json.serialize());

    return utf8Response.c_str();
}
```

Two example outputs on Windows 7:

1. Should be: `{"statusCode": 400,`
   [image: example 1]
2. Should be: `{"status":`
   [image: example2]

Comment: If you're using some library to send an HTTP response, I'd suggest that the problem is in that library rather than the OS.

Comment: UTF8 characters at the beginning of your text are probably BOMs (byte order marks). You could detect when there is a byte order mark at the beginning of your string and remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with character encoding, or OS used. The function is returning a *dangling pointer to invalid memory*!

The function is declaring a local `std::string` variable that goes out of scope when the function exits.  It is returning a pointer to the `std::string`'s internal character data, which is freed when the `std::string` is destroyed.

To solve this, the function will have to return a pointer to *dynamically allocated memory* that the caller can then free (or pass back to the DLL to free) at a later time when it is done using the data.  For example:

```cpp
const char* foo(const char* param)
{
    web::http::http_response resp = other_foo(param).get();
    web::json::value json = resp.extract_json().get();
    std::string utf8Response = utility::conversions::to_utf8string(json.serialize());

    // the caller can use CoTaskMemFree() to free this returned memory...
    size_t size = utf8Response.size() + 1; // +1 for null terminator
    char *ptr = static_cast<char*>(CoTaskMemAlloc(size));
    if (ptr)
        std::memcpy(ptr, utf8Response.c_str(), size);
    return ptr;
}
```

```cpp
const char* response = foo(param);
if (response) {
    ...
    CoTaskMemFree(response);
}
```

Or:

```cpp
const char* foo(const char* param)
{
    web::http::http_response resp = other_foo(param).get();
    web::json::value json = resp.extract_json().get();
    std::string utf8Response = utility::conversions::to_utf8string(json.serialize());

    // the caller must call free_foo_result() to free this memory...
    size_t size = utf8Response.size() + 1; // +1 for null terminator
    char *ptr = new(std::nothrow) char[size];
    if (ptr)
        std::memcpy(ptr, utf8Response.c_str(), size);
    return ptr;
}

void free_foo_result(const char *data)
{
    delete[] data;
}
```

```cpp
const char* response = foo(param);
if (response) {
    ...
    free_foo_result(response);
}
```

If re-writing the EXE to make these extra function calls is not an option, then the DLL will have to cache the JSON data so it can survive past the `return`, eg:

```cpp
const char* foo(const char* param)
{
    static thread_local std::string utf8Response;

    web::http::http_response resp = other_foo(param).get();
    web::json::value json = resp.extract_json().get();
    utf8Response = utility::conversions::to_utf8string(json.serialize());

    return utf8Response.c_str();
}
```

Comment: Good catch.  Don't you think it would be better to return `std::string` directly?

Comment: This can constitute a valid solution (I will check), but why does existing solution work on Windows 10 and does not work on Windows 7 then?

Comment: @user2530062 the original code has *Undefined Behavior*, so literally *anything* can happen, including *seemingly working behavior*. But the code clearly has a logic bug and needs to be fixed.

Comment: @user2530062 the important thing to remember about undefined behavior is that sometimes it can look like it's working.  That's actually the worst outcome, because that means you have a ticking time bomb on your hands.

Comment: @MarkRansom "*Don't you think it would be better to return `std::string` directly?*" No, because the function is from a DLL, and `std::string` (or any non-trivial POD type) is unsafe to pass across the DLL boundary. A DLL uses its own RTL, STL, memory manager/allocator, etc that are separate from whatever the EXE uses. There is no guarantee that the EXE and DLL are even using the same compiler, let alone the same STL implementation, memory layout, etc. Another solution would require the EXE allocate memory that the DLL fills in, but the EXE would have to know the size of the JSON ahead of time

Comment: Knowing the size of the returned string isn't a problem if you provide a way to query the result size before you generate it.  But of course everything else you say makes complete sense.

Comment: @MarkRansom that would require making multiple queries to the web server, assuming it even supports querying the size of the JSON (ie, using a `HEAD` request), which is not always possible for dynamically-generated responses. Otherwise, the DLL would have to make 1 request to get the actual JSON and then cache it internally for multiple function calls to then work with as needed.